# How can I declare a template constant type?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

If I make a typedef such as

```
typedef int const cint;
```

`cint` will refer to an int that can't be modified. I can use `cint` in any context that takes a type (template parameter, function definition, etc).

However, typedefs don't work with templates. My hope is to be able to declare a template like `Constant<SomeType>` and have this refer to a `const SomeType`, the way I can do with `cint` above. Is it possible?

Comment: as simple as `template <typename T> using Constant = const T;`

Comment: `template <typename T> using Constant = const T;` @PiotrS. beat me by 7 sec :(

Comment: the comments should be answers, also, i dont' quiet remember but is "using" template usage a Cx11 feature?

Comment: @NickoPo alias templates are available since C++11

Comment: Wow, that was much faster than I expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++11:

```
template <typename T>
using Constant = const T;

Constant<int> i = 1;
//! i = 2; // error: assignment of read-only variable 'i'
```

C++03:

```
template <typename T>
struct Constant
{
    typedef const T type;
};

Constant<int>::type i = 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

`std::add_const_t<SomeType>` is the same as `const SomeType`.

Comment: I was just about to add this to my answer `+1`